Springboot - Hibernate - Postgres Pessimistic Locking not work
I am working on a project using Java 17.0.11, Spring Boot 3.1.1, Hibernate, and Postgres. I have a piece of code that has high concurrency requirements, and I used a pessimistic lock hoping to ensure that every time the function is called, it gets the most up-to-date data. Here is the code:
pom
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.my.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>myapp</name>
    <description>myapp</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                <artifactId>testcontainers-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.17.5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JPA-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- redis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- column validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- email -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
// ......

Controller:
public void processStockOut(
        @RequestBody @Valid PDADestockingStockOutDTO pdaDestockingStockOutDTO,
        @RequestHeader(value = "pda-version", required = false) String version) {
        log.info("[PDA][DEPART][{}][START] requestBody: {}",           pdaDestockingStockOutDTO.getDestockingId(), JacksonSerializeUtil.serialize(pdaDestockingStockOutDTO));
        app5ExStock.pdaDepart(pdaDestockingStockOutDTO, version, GlobalParam.getUserName());
        log.info("[PDA][DEPART][{}][END]", pdaDestockingStockOutDTO.getDestockingId());
    }

Repository:
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
@Query("from Outbound where id =:id")
Optional<Outbound> findByIdForUpdate(@Param("id") String id);

Service:
@Transactional
public void pdaDepart(PDADestockingStockOutDTO pdaDestockingStockOutDTO, String version, String userName) {
    Outbound outbound = outboundRepository.findByIdForUpdate(pdaDestockingStockOutDTO.getDestockingId())
            .orElseThrow(() -> new BadRequestException(DESTOCKING_NOT_FOUND));
    // Log the status of the outbound
    log.info("[PDA][DEPART][{}] {}", outbound.getId(), outbound.getStatus());

    if (outbound.getStatus() == OutboundStatusEnum.STOCK_OUT) {
        throw new InternalServerException("Déjà Départ avec succès");
    }

    // ...
    domainOutbound.exStock(outbound, stockOutAt);
    // ...
}

@Transactional
public void exStock(Outbound outbound, LocalDateTime stockOutAt) {
    outbound.setStatus(OutboundStatusEnum.STOCK_OUT);
    outbound.setStockOutAt(stockOutAt);
    outboundRepository.save(outbound);
}

application.yml
spring:
  jpa:
    database: POSTGRESQL
    generate-ddl: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    properties:
      hibernate:
        connection:
          isolation: 2

// ......

In practical use cases, due to frontend design issues, there are situations where a button that should be clicked only once ends up being clicked multiple times. This leads to the controller being triggered multiple times. I expect the subsequent function triggers to fetch the latest data (which should have already been updated to STOCK_OUT by the first function call). However, most of the time (but not always), it fetches the old data (STOCK_IN).
Interestingly, this issue never occurs during local debugging; it only happens on the production server. I have similarly used pessimistic locking in other parts of the application, and they occasionally fail as well.
NORMAL Log Info
just one [END] and one 'STOCK_IN'
Jul 16 15:16:19 my-app-api app[web] INFO 2024-07-16 13:16:19 INFO  c.c.m.a.b.p.PdaStep4And5StockOutController:118 - 0 0 - [PDA][DEPART][L-FR-16072024-2992][START] requestBody: {"destockingId":"L-FR-16072024-2992","licensePlate":"R0234BCS","bindingSwapBodyList":[{"id":"00686203","plomb":"00686203"}],"isUploaded":true,"isCmr2Uploaded":true}
Jul 16 15:16:19 my-app-api app[web] INFO 2024-07-16 13:16:19 INFO  c.c.m.s.App5ExStock:1243 - 0 0 - [PDA][DEPART][L-FR-16072024-2992] STOCK_IN
Jul 16 15:16:21 my-app-api app[web] INFO 2024-07-16 13:16:21 INFO  c.c.m.a.b.p.PdaStep4And5StockOutController:118 - 0 0 - [PDA][DEPART][L-FR-16072024-2992][START] requestBody: {"destockingId":"L-FR-16072024-2992","licensePlate":"R0234BCS","bindingSwapBodyList":[{"id":"00686203","plomb":"00686203"}],"isUploaded":true,"isCmr2Uploaded":true}
Jul 16 15:16:23 my-app-api app[web] INFO 2024-07-16 13:16:23 INFO  c.c.m.a.b.p.PdaStep4And5StockOutController:118 - 0 0 - [PDA][DEPART][L-FR-16072024-2992][START] requestBody: {"destockingId":"L-FR-16072024-2992","licensePlate":"R0234BCS","bindingSwapBodyList":[{"id":"00686203","plomb":"00686203"}],"isUploaded":true,"isCmr2Uploaded":true}
Jul 16 15:16:24 my-app-api app[web] INFO 2024-07-16 13:16:24 INFO  c.c.m.a.b.p.PdaStep4And5StockOutController:118 - 0 0 - [PDA][DEPART][L-FR-16072024-2992][START] requestBody: {"destockingId":"L-FR-16072024-2992","licensePlate":"R0234BCS","bindingSwapBodyList":[{"id":"00686203","plomb":"00686203"}],"isUploaded":true,"isCmr2Uploaded":true}
Jul 16 15:16:26 my-app-api app[web] INFO 2024-07-16 13:16:26 INFO  c.c.m.a.b.p.PdaStep4And5StockOutController:118 - 0 0 - [PDA][DEPART][L-FR-16072024-2992][START] requestBody: {"destockingId":"L-FR-16072024-2992","licensePlate":"R0234BCS","bindingSwapBodyList":[{"id":"00686203","plomb":"00686203"}],"isUploaded":true,"isCmr2Uploaded":true}
Jul 16 15:16:29 my-app-api app[web] INFO 2024-07-16 13:16:29 INFO  c.c.m.a.b.p.PdaStep4And5StockOutController:120 - 0 0 - [PDA][DEPART][L-FR-16072024-2992][END]
Jul 16 15:16:29 my-app-api app[web] INFO 2024-07-16 13:16:29 INFO  c.c.m.s.App5ExStock:1243 - 0 0 - [PDA][DEPART][L-FR-16072024-2992] STOCK_OUT
Jul 16 15:16:29 my-app-api app[web] INFO 2024-07-16 13:16:29 INFO  c.c.m.s.App5ExStock:1243 - 0 0 - [PDA][DEPART][L-FR-16072024-2992] STOCK_OUT
Jul 16 15:16:29 my-app-api app[web] INFO 2024-07-16 13:16:29 INFO  c.c.m.s.App5ExStock:1243 - 0 0 - [PDA][DEPART][L-FR-16072024-2992] STOCK_OUT
Jul 16 15:16:29 my-app-api app[web] INFO 2024-07-16 13:16:29 INFO  c.c.m.s.App5ExStock:1243 - 0 0 - [PDA][DEPART][L-FR-16072024-2992] STOCK_OUT

ERROR Log Info:
multiple [END] and 'STOCK_IN'
Jul 16 13:33:17 my-app-api app[web] INFO 2024-07-16 11:33:17 INFO  c.c.m.a.b.p.PdaStep4And5StockOutController:118 - 0 0 - [PDA][DEPART][IT-POZ-POS2024071529999][START] requestBody: {"destockingId":"IT-POZ-POS2024071529999","licensePlate":"AA247AA","bindingSwapBodyList":[{"plomb":"00689999"}],"isUploaded":true}
Jul 16 13:33:17 my-app-api app[web] INFO 2024-07-16 11:33:17 INFO  c.c.m.s.App5ExStock:1243 - 0 0 - [PDA][DEPART][IT-POZ-POS2024071529999] STOCK_IN
Jul 16 13:33:24 my-app-api app[web] INFO 2024-07-16 11:33:24 INFO  c.c.m.a.b.p.PdaStep4And5StockOutController:120 - 0 0 - [PDA][DEPART][IT-POZ-POS2024071529999][END]
Jul 16 13:33:24 my-app-api app[web] INFO 2024-07-16 11:33:24 INFO  c.c.m.a.b.p.PdaStep4And5StockOutController:118 - 0 0 - [PDA][DEPART][IT-POZ-POS2024071529999][START] requestBody: {"destockingId":"IT-POZ-POS2024071529999","licensePlate":"AA247AA","bindingSwapBodyList":[{"plomb":"00689999"}],"isUploaded":true}
Jul 16 13:33:24 my-app-api app[web] INFO 2024-07-16 11:33:24 INFO  c.c.m.s.App5ExStock:1243 - 0 0 - [PDA][DEPART][IT-POZ-POS2024071529999] STOCK_IN
Jul 16 13:33:27 my-app-api app[web] INFO 2024-07-16 11:33:27 INFO  c.c.m.a.b.p.PdaStep4And5StockOutController:120 - 0 0 - [PDA][DEPART][IT-POZ-POS2024071529999][END]

This is the Hibernate SQL statement:
select o1_0.id, o1_0.archive, o1_0.archive_by, o1_0.archive_first_reason, o1_0.archive_second_reason, o1_0.cargo_index, o1_0.comment, o1_0.create_type, o1_0.created_at, o1_0.created_by, o1_0.destination, o1_0.expected_arrival_time, o1_0.license_plate, o1_0.outbound_mode, o1_0.pallet_quantity, o1_0.pre_ex_stock_at, o1_0.receiver, o1_0.route_transport_type, o1_0.scheduled_time, o1_0.seals, o1_0.status, o1_0.stock_out_at, o1_0.third_part, o1_0.transport_order_id, o1_0.transport_order_ref, o1_0.updated_at, o1_0.updated_by, o1_0.upload_cmr_at, o1_0.upload_dau_at, o1_0.upload_pod_at, o1_0.warehouse
from whs_outbound o1_0
where (o1_0.archive = false)
and o1_0.id=?
for no key update

I found that through checking the database lock, my database generates a shared lock instead of an exclusive lock. Why is that?
How can I ensure that the pessimistic lock is effective?
I'd like the pessimistic lock to work properly, with the updated data on the second fetch

Where is your version field?

Pessimistic Locking. In this type of locking, we prevent other users from performing operations on data tables or rows !!!until the transaction is completed!!!. Use debug with break-point before transaction end and then lunch the second request.

These codes in localhost debug mode it works, but in my server it doesn't work, this is what I don't understande

In your log you can see that [END] of first transaction is before second request starts. Hense your lock doesn't work no more

But if the second transaction is opened after the first transaction is closed, shouldn't I get the data after it was updated by one transaction? But what I'm actually getting is the data before it was modified. @WladimirDiskowski

which version field? @K.Nicholas

Can you turn on Hibernate or Postgres logging and see what queries are actually sent? It's possible that 2 separate queries are issued - one for the usual SELECT, and then it goes through the returned objects and issues additional SELECT ... FOR UPDATE. Or maybe you selected the same object elsewhere. Also, instead of the pessimistic locking you could use SNAPSHOT isolation level (it's actually called REPEATABLE READ in PG even though it's not the right name) - this would throw an error if 2 transactions modified the same row - you'd have to handle it and restart the transaction.

@StanislavBashkyrtsev I have tried to use @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ) , but nothing changes.

Then check if your @Transactional actually works and you don't work accidentally outside of the transactional block. And do check your SQL statements!

@StanislavBashkyrtsev I have updated my description with the Hibernate SQL statement. My transaction isolation level is Read Committed. I understand that in this case, if the second transaction starts before the first transaction commits, it will read the old data. However, according to the log described, my second transaction starts after the first transaction ends. Why does it still read the old data? Do you know the reason?

Here is some adjustment:
@Transactional 
public void pdaDepart(PDADestockingStockOutDTO pdaDestockingStockOutDTO, 
  String version, String userName) {
  Outbound outbound = outboundRepository.findByIdForUpdate(pdaDestockingStockOutDTO.getDestockingId())
        .orElseThrow(() -> new BadRequestException(DESTOCKING_NOT_FOUND));
  log.info("[PDA][DEPART][{}] {}", outbound.getId(), outbound.getStatus());

  if (outbound.getStatus() == OutboundStatusEnum.STOCK_OUT) {
    throw new InternalServerException("Déjà Départ avec succès");
  }
  domainOutbound.exStock(outbound, stockOutAt);
  outboundRepository.save(outbound);
  log.info("[PDA][DEPART][{}] Transaction completed", pdaDestockingStockOutDTO.getDestockingId());
}

and check in your application.properties that you have configured the lock correctly for pessimistic locking
#TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.isolation=2 


But in my "exStock" method I have already wrote "save", is there a difference if I write it twice?

try to  remove the method and add all the lines of code after the if statement

omg it works, why !!!!!

I think the method should be either in the same class otherwise it should be called from an injected bean and if it is in a separate class it must have @Transactional operation, even now if you copied all the line of codes you don't need to call the save explicitly cause in transactional method any change on the object will be committed at the end of the transaction

ah no, the problem is still there :(

This piece of code is quite strange. It works sometimes but fails at other times. I've also encountered this issue with pessimistic locking in other places within my application.

how it work sometimes and sometimes no. Did you configured the lock correctly? and can you share test scenario when it succeed and when it wont just to have a clear idea and track the precise problem

I have edit the description
